# Bind Image to CardViewBinaryImageColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview, aspx-user-control

I have a simple CardView:

```
  <dx:ASPxCardView ID="CardViewProfile" runat="server" KeyFieldName="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <dx:CardViewBinaryImageColumn FieldName="Photo">
                <PropertiesBinaryImage ImageHeight="175px">
                    <EditingSettings Enabled="true" UploadSettings-UploadValidationSettings-MaxFileSize="4194304" />
                </PropertiesBinaryImage>
            </dx:CardViewBinaryImageColumn>
            <dx:CardViewMemoColumn FieldName="Id" Caption="Codice Utente" ReadOnly="true"/>
            <dx:CardViewTextColumn FieldName="Name"/>
            <dx:CardViewTextColumn FieldName="Surname"/>

        </Columns>
        <CardLayoutProperties ColCount="3">
            <Items>
                <dx:CardViewColumnLayoutItem ColumnName="Photo" ShowCaption="False" ColSpan="1" RowSpan="4"/>
                <dx:CardViewColumnLayoutItem ColumnName="Id" />
                <dx:CardViewColumnLayoutItem ColumnName="Name" />
                <dx:CardViewColumnLayoutItem ColumnName="Surname" />
            </Items>
        </CardLayoutProperties>
    </dx:ASPxCardView>
```

And I bind it like this:

```
User user = DBContext.getUserByID(user_id);
List<User> datasource = new List<User>();
datasource.Add(user);

CardViewProfile.DataSource = datasource;
CardViewProfile.DataBind();
```

The object `User` contains: Id, Name, Surname and a Photo field containing a string representing the path of the picture on the server.
How do I bind this picture to the CardViewBinaryImageColumn? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know that control in question, but does the image control not have a src of some sort? You  could also just drop in a plan jane image control, and set scr of the  image control to the expression for the path name to the picture - it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<dx:CardViewBinaryImageColumn />` is used for showing images from binary data.

If you want to display an image using a url, try replacing the column with the following:

```
 <dx:CardViewImageColumn FieldName="Photo" Caption="Photo" />
```

Dev Express have an example: Deve https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxCardViewDemos/Adaptivity/AdaptiveLayout.aspx?device=tablet&rotate=0